# Let $G$ be a group, $G'=[G,G]$ and $G''=[G',G']$ the first and second derived subgroups and assume $G''$ is cyclic. Prove that $G''\subset Z(G')$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove the following, but I'm stuck and I don't see how to continue. Any help is much appreciated!

> Let $G$ be a group, $G'=[G,G]$ and $G''=[G',G']$ the first and second derived subgroups and assume $G''$ is cyclic. Prove that $G''\subset Z(G')$.

My work this far: Since $G''$ is cyclic, it is abelian. Since it is the commutator subgroup of $G'$, it is also known that $G''$ is normal. Thus (using a theorem from my syllabus), there exists a homomorphism $g:G'/G''\to\mathrm{Aut}(G'')$ such that $g(aG'')=\phi_{a|G''}$ for $a\in G'$, where $\phi_{a|G'}:G''\to G'':x\mapsto axa^{-1}$, thus the conjugation map by $a$. Now it suffices to proof $\phi_{a|G'}=Id_{G'}$ for all $a\in G'$.

But how to prove this? I don't see it. The work I did this far follows a hint that was given for the question.

Comment: This result follows from the fact that ${\rm Aut}(G'')$ is abelian.

Comment: I understand that $\mathrm{Aut}(G'')$ is abelian, but I don't see how this follows. Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: So $G'$ is in the kernel of the homomorphism $G \to {\rm Aut}(G'')$ induced by conjugation.

Comment: Sorry but I just don't understand what you mean. Why should $G'$ be in the kernel of the homomorphism $G\to\rm{Aut}(G'')$?

Comment: Because, as we have already agreed,  ${\rm Aut}(G'')$ is abelian.

Comment: I understand $\rm{Aut}(G'')$ is abelian, because $G''$ is cyclic, thus isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or to $C_n$, for an $n\in\mathbb{N}$, thus $\rm{Aut}(G'')$ is isomorphic to either $C_2$ or $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. My question is how we can infer from $\rm{Aut}(G'')$ being abelian that $G'$ is in the kernel of the homomorphism you mention. That is the part I don't get

Comment: If $A$ is any abelian group and $G\to A$ any homomorphism, then $G'$ is in the kernel. This is a "universal property" of the derived subgroup $G'$. It follows because any commutator becomes the identity element in an abelian group.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I think I can finish of my proof now! Am I right that this is a consequence of the homomorphism theorem? @anon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $N_G(H)/C_G(H) \hookrightarrow Aut(H)$, by conjugation. Now take $H=G''$, being cyclic. Then $Aut(G'')$ is abelian. Since $G''$ is normal in $G$ we have $N_G(G'')=G$ and so $G/C_G(G'')$ is abelian, whence $G' \subseteq C_G(G'')$. That is, $G'$ centralizes $G''$, or equivalenty $G'' \subseteq Z(G')$.

Comment: Thank you! It was essentially that I forget about $G/N$ abelian $\iff G'\subset N$. It is much clearer now

Comment: OK, glad you remembered it!

Comment: why is $G''$ normal in $G$? if $N$ is normal in $H$ and $H$ is normal in $G$, does not mean $N$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: You can prove this directly, $G”$, and all members of the derived series of $G$ are even *characteristic*, whence normal.